# How do I load a save from an old version of Tekkit?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tekkit

Around October 2012, I started playing Technic (it was still Minecraft 1.2.5 Minecraft). I stopped playing about 1 month later, and I just found a backup of the save file.

Is there any way to load that file and keep all the stuff? I heard the new pack has IC2 removed, so I know the new pack won't work.

Tekkit classic didn't work. Only vanilla items are there... No ironchests, IC2, RP2 stuff, etc... I'm playing in SSP, and if I remember right Tekkit was server, Technic was single. How do I get single player technic?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite understand the question(s). You're trying to load an old save with a new version? Have you already attempted or are you just assuming it won't work? Also, "How do I get single player technic?" I don't really understand. Technic is the single player version of the mod pack, though you can play Tekkit single player as well.

Comment: Are you trying to find the version of Technic that the world would play with, or just the latest version of Technic with the mods you had installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old Technic SSP is removed in favor of the newer packs. There was a custom modpack which brought it back, but it apparently stopped working for unknown reasons. [You can find it here.](http://www.technicpack.net/modpack/details/removed-modpack.21133) Maybe you can manage to get it working, the problem seems to be in modpack.jar.

I still had the old Technic Launcher somewhere a few years ago, and I was able to download Technic SSP using it. If you still have the old launcher, maybe you'll have more luck.

If you don't have the old launcher, then I'm sorry, but you will have to move on.

Answer (score -1):

If you have opened the world and all the blocks/items are gone, and you do not have a backup, then the items are gone for good. Even if you do have a backup, you would need to install all the mods (probably manually, as technic before the launcher probably doesn't exist anymore), and then config all the block id-s correctly (which is also unlikely to exist on the internet).

Comment: Technic as-it-was definitely doesn't exist anymore—it was discontinued and restarted later because many mods were being distributed without permission before.